# Can't find downloadimageurl to download image for collection view cell image

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, uicollectionview

I am stuck on something that is probably quite a simple fix, but I can not seem to figure it out. So I have an instagram like app I am working on and am currently working on setting up the feed, a guy on youtube provides a great video on how to set up the feed. So I have completed much of the project and hooked it up to firebase, created an nsobject for posts that include a string for postID and pathToImage. Firebase setup: https://i.stack.imgur.com/whDA7.jpg and there is a post object class with a couple strings. I included the image because showing a lot of code that might be unimportant Here is my collectionview code:

```
 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
  return posts.count
}
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! UserFeedCollectionViewCell

 ->   cell.myImage. downloadImage(from: String)   <- does not exist, or doesn't show up. 
    cell.myImage.layer.cornerRadius = 12.0
    cell.myImage.clipsToBounds = true

    return cell
}
```

So if you can see I cannot get downloadUrl to work and the guy in the video was able to do it with autocomplete, please help if you can. Thank you

Comment: `downloadImage` is not part of native `UIImage` or `UIImageView` class. If `autocomplete` don't work and compiling fail, it means you are missing an `import`. Check on the video and see what is missing. I couldn't see from the image posted.

Comment: umm it looks that he has the same imported files as me, uikit and firebase

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can realize it with Kingfisher for example. And works better. [link](https://github.com/onevcat/Kingfisher)
It will also cache your images.

How to use: Add link to your image from storage to database item node. Like this:

[image]

Then just use it to present and cache image.

Example:

```
 let imageView = UIImageView(frame: frame) // init with frame for example
 imageView.kf.setImage(with: <urlForYourImageFromFireBase>) //Using kf for caching images
```

In your case if cell.myImage is UIImageView:

```
cell.myImage.kf.setImage(with: <urlForYourImageFromFireBase>) //Using kf for caching images
```

Hope it helps